# Rendition of Project Euler 26 - reciprocal cycles

Tags: python, python-2.x, programming-challenge

This is my solution for [problem 26 from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26):

```
"""Find the value of d < 1000 for which 
1/d contains the longest recurring cycle 
in its decimal fraction part."""

from timeit import default_timer as timer
import math
from decimal import *

start = timer()

def longestPeriod(n): # define function
    longest = [0, 0] # length, num

    def isPrime(k): # checks if a # is prime
        for x in range(2, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(k)))):
            if k % x == 0:
            return False
        return True

    def primeFact(k): # returns prime factorization of # in list
        if k <= 1: return []
        prime = next((x for x in range(2, 
            int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(k))+1)) if k%x == 0), k)

        return [prime] + primeFact(k//prime) 

    def periodIfPrime(k):
        period = 1
        while (10**period - 1) % k != 0:
            period += 1

        return period # returns period of 1/d if d is prime

    def lcm(numbers): # finds lcm of list of #s
        def __gcd(a, b):
            a = int(a)
            b = int(b)
            while b:
                a,b = b,a%b
            return a
        def __lcm(a, b):
            return ( a * b ) / __gcd(a, b)

        return reduce(__lcm, numbers)

    for x in range(3, n): # check all up to d for 1/d

        if all(p == 2 or p == 5 for p in primeFact(x)) == True: # doesn't repeat
            pass

        elif isPrime(x) is True: # run prime function
            if longest[0] < periodIfPrime(x):
                longest = [periodIfPrime(x), x]

        elif len(primeFact(x)) == 2 and primeFact(x)[0] == primeFact(x)[1]:
            if x == 3 or x == 487 or x == 56598313: # exceptions
                period = int(math.sqrt(x))
            else: # square of prime
                period = periodIfPrime(primeFact(x)[0]) * x
                if period > longest:
                    longest = [period, x]

        else:
            fact = primeFact(x)
            periods = []
            for k in fact:
                if k != 2 and k != 5:
                    if fact.count(k) == 1:
                        periods.append(periodIfPrime(k))
                    else:
                        periods.append((periodIfPrime(k)) * k**(fact.count(k) - 1))

            if lcm(periods) > longest[0]:
                longest = [lcm(periods), x] 

            return longest

elapsed_time = timer() - start
elapsed_time /= 100 # milliseconds

print "Found %d in %r ms." % (longestPeriod(1000)[1], elapsed_time)
```

Can it be written in a better way?

Comment: You shouldn't update the code you've written as it makes the answers irrelevant. Please rollback your change and if you really want to, add the new code precising explicitely that you've taken answers into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Don't compute the same thing more than once. You call `primeFact(x)` up to 5 times for each `x`. Keep the result in a variable instead.
- You check if `x` is prime after you have already computed its prime factorization. Now think for a minute: how does the prime factorization of a prime turn out?
- Your program would greatly benefit from a precomputed list of primes. Look up sieve of Eratosthenes.
- The answer according to this program is 3, which cannot be right, as eg. 7 has a longer period already.
- Bug: `if period > longest` compares an `int` to a `list`, which is not an error in Python 2.x, but does not do what you want.
- To allow testing of individual functions, it is better to define them at module level.
- A quick test of `isPrime` shows it returns `True` for 4,9,25 etc. That's because eg. `ceil(2.0) == 2.0`

Comment: When you say the answer according to the program is 3, do you mean that it returns 3? I get 983 (the correct answer) when I run it.

Comment: @jshuaf Yes. I had another look, and I see `return longest` must be at the wrong indentation level. Oh I see you just fixed it!

Comment: @jshuaf But now I see you have incorporated my suggestions in the code, which invalidates my answer. Please don't do that; you can post both versions in the question if you like.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to define your own `gcd` function: it [already exists](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd) in the `fractions` module of the standard library. And actually, it works with any integer type. Therefore, you can rewrite `lcm` as:

```
def lcm(numbers):
    """finds lcm of list of #s"""
    from fractions import gcd
    return reduce(lambda a,b: (a*b)/gcd(a, b), numbers)
```

---

Also, you shouldn't write `== True` in a conditional, a code like

```
if eggs == True:
    # do something
```

should be replaced by:

```
if eggs:
    # do something
```

---

I realized that youare actually using Python 2 (for some reason, I thought that you were using Python 3). Therefore, You can probably improve the function `isPrime`. You are currently using `range` in the function. `range` creates and returns a list. You should use `xrange` instead: `xrange` is a generator; it will generate and yield a new `int` at each iteration. Since you occasionally `return` early from your loop, you don"t always need to compute the whole list of integers, and `xrange` should be a best fit for this job.

```
def isPrime(k):
    for x in xrange(2, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(k)))):
        if k % x == 0:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not measuring the elapsed time in a meaningful way.  The bulk of the work is in *calling* the `longestPeriod()` function, not in *defining* it.  You've stopped the timer before you even call the function.

To convert seconds to milliseconds, multiply by 1000, don't divide by 100.

```
start = timer()
answer = longestPeriod(1000)[1]          # Don't you want [0] instead?
elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 1000  # seconds → milliseconds

print "Found %d in %r ms." % (answer, elapsed_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I used [0] because the problem asked for the number, not the length of the period.

Comment: You're right, I read the code carelessly. I suggest using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of a two-element list to avoid such confusion.